# Register key press and release separately c++

Tags: c++, keypress

I am trying to make a console version of pong. I have gotten most of the work done, but have run into an annoying issue.
The player is controlled with the arrow keys, but when they are held down there is a delay before they repeat. I am looking for a way to register when a key is pressed separately to when it is released, so I can eliminate this problem.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

#define FX 101
#define FY 30

void clearmid();
void drawplayer(int playerpos);


int fieldx = FX;
int fieldy = FY;
char field[FY][FX];


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

        initscr();
        //raw();
        noecho();
        keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

        int i, j;
        /* Clear Playing Field */
        for(i = 0; i != fieldy; i++){
                for(j = 0; j != fieldx; j++){
                        field[i][j] = '#';
                }
        }
        /* Add in Newlines so field can be printed as one string */
        for(i = 0; i != fieldy - 1; i++){
                field[i][fieldx - 1] = '\n';
        }
        field[fieldy - 1][fieldx - 1] = '\0';   // Null terminator

        int player1pos, player2pos;
        int ballx, bally, ballxv, ballyv;
        player1pos = fieldy / 2;
        player2pos = player1pos;
        ballx = (fieldx - 1) / 2;
        bally = player1pos;

        /* Ball velocity in given axis */
        ballxv = 1;
        ballyv = 1;


        int c;
        timeout(0);
        while(1){
                c = 0;
                c = getch();
                switch(c){
                        case KEY_UP:{
                                if(player1pos > 2){
                                        player1pos--;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        case KEY_DOWN:{
                                if(player1pos < fieldy - 3){
                                        player1pos++;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        case 'q':{
                                endwin();
                                return 0;
                        }
                        default:{
                                break;
                        }
                }

                clearmid();
                drawplayer(player1pos);

                if((field[bally - 1][ballx] != ' ') || (field[bally + 1][ballx] != ' ')){
                        if(ballyv == 1) ballyv = -1;
                        else ballyv = 1;
                }
                if((field[bally][ballx - 1] != ' ') || (field[bally][ballx + 1] != ' ')){
                        if(ballxv == 1) ballxv = -1;
                        else ballxv = 1;
                }
                ballx += ballxv;
                bally += ballyv;
                field[bally][ballx] = '*';

                move(0,0);
                printw("%s", field);
                refresh();
                usleep(30000);
        }
        return 0;
}

void drawplayer(int playerpos){
        field[playerpos-1][2] = '|';
        field[playerpos][2] = '|';
        field[playerpos+1][2] = '|';
}


void clearmid(){
        int i, j;
        for(i = 1; i != fieldy -1; i++){
                for(j = 1; j != fieldx - 2; j++){
                        field[i][j] = ' ';
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consoles don't typically perform such functionality. You could try ncurses, I guess. Else, you will have to go to your favourite operating system's API.

Answer (score 1):

There's no possibility to get key release events with a terminal API like ncurses. You can turn the keyboard repeat off, like setterm(1) does (look at the source), but this is not guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too easy since you are using a console, and not something like SDL.

I would suggest having the user input section of code (`KEY_UP`, etc.) flag a boolean `true` when the key is pressed. Then in the rendering code, check to see if this boolean is true, and if it is then update the player position accordingly.

In this way the position is updated every frame and not just when the user input is received.

If you could check when the key is released, that is when you set the boolean to false to stop moving the player.

One thing to watch out for, is the player may end up moving too fast. If this is the case then you would need to limit how often the position is updated to X amount of times per second, or something similar. This also makes sure that those with fast computers do not move their player faster than those with slower machines.

I hope this all makes sense and gives you an idea to work off of.

Comment: That speed thing wouldn't be a problem since the "framerate" is controlled by delaying with usleep(3000); And yes, I wan to do exactly what you suggested, but I need to be able to tell when the key is released to do that.